# Copy IEnumerables or ICollections into an EXISITING array entry-wise

Tags: c#, arrays, collections, copy

I have two `IEnumerable`s already filled and an array large enough to store all elements of both of them:

```
IEnumerable<int> foo = ... // contains some elements.
IEnumerable<int> bar = ... // contains some elements.

int[] array = ... // already existing. array.Length is at least foo.Count + bar.Count
```

I want to copy the elements of `foo` and `bar` into `array`. And I would like to be able to do this without creating new objects (like LINQ would do when calling `Concat` or `ToArray`). In my concrete scenario, I do not care about the order, as it will be sorted later. A way to achieve it is this:

```
int k = 0;
foreach (int i in foo)
    array[k++] = i;
foreach (int i in bar)
    array[k++] = i;
```

I would like to know if there is some built-in method that does the copying for me (for convenience purposes), similar to LINQ `ToArray` or `Concat`, but without needing to create new objects. Giving ranges as input would be nice, too. A method like below maybe?

```
// desired way:
foo.InsertIntoArray(0) // insert the elements of foo into array starting at index 0
bar.InsertIntoArray(foo.Count) // insert the elements of bar into array starting at index foo.Count
```

I know the `Array.Copy` method, but as far as I know, it only works to copy from array to array, not from `IEnumerable` to array. Is there something alike?

Comment: _"without iterating through a loop"_ -- what do you mean? Even `Buffer.BlockCopy()` involves a loop. If you want to avoid writing a loop in your code, you can easily write your own helper method to accomplish this. There is not a method in `Array` or `Enumerable` to do precisely what you're asking, but it's trivial to implement one yourself. You can even make it an extension method a la the `Enumerable` class. But however you do it, there will have to be a loop _somewhere_.

Comment: I meant "without needing to write loops in my code". What happens internally does not matter to me, as long as it does not create a new `IEnumerable` or `array`. Writing a helper method still involves writing loops myself. I just want to know if there are methods that do that for me. If the answer is "no", this is not a reason to vote down, I'd say.

Comment: _"Writing a helper method still involves writing loops myself"_ -- it involves writing _a single loop_ yourself. Once. Why is that bad? After all, the mythical `InsertIntoArray()` method would have a loop. And why do you want to avoid creating a new `IEnumerable`? The code you show above creates _two_. Why don't you want to create a new array? The code above does. It really is not clear what you want at all.

Comment: @PeterDuniho "Why is that bad?" - it is inconvenient. Why do all the LINQ extension methods for collections exist? Not because they add new functionality, but because they are convenient. If asking for an existing method that one could easily write oneself is such an evil thing, why do people keep asking (here on SO as well)? Array.Copy is one of those methods that is easily written in a single loop. So we should not have it, right? And we should not ask for it, right? But we do (both).

Comment: You are missing the point. Your specifications are unclear. There does not seem to be a method in .NET that meets your specifications, but without you explaining why the constraints you've put on the question exist, no one can reasonably understand what answer would address your question. No one, least of all me, is saying that because you could write it easily, it shouldn't be in the framework. What I _am_ saying is that you need to be clear about what your actual need is, and especially explain why constraints that even your own code example doesn't meet are being included here.

Comment: I don't understand what is unclear. I have several `IEnumerable`s and want to put all or part of their elements in an array that is big enough to hold them, without creating unnecessary objects (as LINQ does). What else do I have to specify or explain? What constraints are not met by my own code example?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> foo = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
List<int> bar = new List<int> { 3, 4, 5 };

//This will give you all items from both collections
var array = Enumerable.Concat(foo, bar).ToArray(); // 1,2,3,3,4,5
var array = foo.Concat(bar).ToArray();

//This will give you all distinct items
var array = Enumerable.Union(foo, bar).ToArray(); //1,2,3,4,5
var array = foo.Union(bar).ToArray();
```

You can also:

```
List<int> result = new List<int>();
result.AddRange(foo);
result.AddRange(bar);

result.InsertRange(result.Count, foo);
result.InsertRange(result.Count, bar);

foo.AddRange(bar); //But was assuming you don't want to change the existing list
```

But Both [InsertRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/884ee1fz(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) and [AddRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) reallocate the internal array - And I assume Concut/Union use these behind the scenes

Comment: Does this not create a lot of new `IEnumerable`s? As far as I know, `Concat` and `ToArray` always create new objects, so this is not what I want.

Comment: @Kjara - I've added to `ToArray` just because you wanted it as an array

Answer (score 0):

If your `IEnumerable` object also implements `ICollection`, you can cast it to `ICollection` and use the `CopyTo` method provided by this interface, otherwise you can only write loops. I actually looked at the source code for `Enumerable.ToArray`, and that's what Microsoft does.